# C# Bitmap Byte Array to Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I've saved some bitmaps to a database as an array of bytes.

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    stream.Position = 0;
    bitmapData = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(bitmapData, 0, (int)stream.Length);
    stream.Close();
}
```

I'd like to transfer the data using MVC4 Web API to a javascript client. Do I need to change anything or is it possible like this? Can I just convert the byte array to a base64 string and use it directly inside image element ?

Comment: You need to use a `data:` URI.

Comment: Yeah but can i just use the converted bitmap object bytes as base64

Comment: Yes, except that you should use PNG or JPEG (for photos) instead of BMP.